# Linq js group by Sum appending string instead of adding

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I am using linq.js
"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js"

The objective is to get "sum" of a field using group by clause. The code is working fine but "quantity" is considered as a string and appending numbers. If I use g.Sum(parseInt("$.quantity")) or parseFloat I am getting error b is not a function. What am I missing?

- If I want set some initial value to quantity, how can I?

  ```
   aggregatedData = Enumerable.From(someData)
       .GroupBy("$.id", null,
           function (key, g) {
               return {
                   stock: key,
                   quantity: g.Sum("$.quantity"),
                   avgprice: g.Average("$.average_price")
               }
           })
       .ToArray();
  ```

Comment: Can you please update the question by adding the values of `someData`? That way, we will know what kind of data is being used.

Comment: I figured it out.. g.Sum(function (s) { return parseFloat(s.quantity | 0); })

Comment: You should consider posting this as an answer and accepting it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. `g.Sum(function (s) { return parseFloat(s.quantity | 0); })`